# setInterval() and clearInterval() in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Hello mighty people from internet,

I am trying to build a countdown timer app with pause and reset buttons using React hooks.

The timer countdown should stop once pause or reset button gets clicked performed by function pauseCountDown() and reset(), respectively.

However, the timer does not stop after pauseCountDown() or reset() executed.
I don’t quite understand why setInterval() does not stop after clearInterval() gets executed.

clearInterval() should be executed when **isPaused === true**.
However, the value of “isPaused” instantly switches back to false along with the next iteration of nonstopped setInterval().

Any ideas or thoughts what I missed or mistakes I have?

Thank you.

Here is the code of the child component performing timer countdown:

```
function TimerPanel(props) {
  var launch;
  var secLeft = parseInt(props.timerNow.min) * 60 + parseInt(props.timerNow.sec)

  const startCountDown = () => {
    props.setIsPaused(false)
    launch = setInterval(decrement, 1000)
  }
  function decrement() {
    if (secLeft > 0 && !props.isPaused) {
      secLeft--;
      var minCountDown = Math.floor(secLeft / 60)
      var secCountDown = Math.floor((secLeft % 60) * 100) / 100
      props.setTimerNow({...props.timerNow, min: minCountDown, sec: secCountDown})
    }
  }
  const pauseCountDown = () => {
    props.setIsPaused(true)
    clearInterval(launch)
  }
  const reset = () => {
    props.setIsPaused(false)
    clearInterval(launch)
    props.setSessionLength(props.initialTimer.min);
    props.setTimerNow({...props.timerNow, min: props.initialTimer.min, sec: props.initialTimer.sec})
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `launch` is just an ordinary variable, its value will not survive across rerenderings of `TimerPanel`. You'll need to store it inside a [ref](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#is-there-something-like-instance-variables) with [`useRef`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref)

```
// add useRef to your imports from react
import { useRef } from "react";

function TimerPanel(props) {
  const launch = useRef();
  var secLeft =
    parseInt(props.timerNow.min) * 60 + parseInt(props.timerNow.sec);

  const startCountDown = () => {
    props.setIsPaused(false);
    clearInterval(launch.current) // clean up any old timers
    launch.current = setInterval(decrement, 1000);
  };
  function decrement() {
    if (secLeft > 0 && !props.isPaused) {
      secLeft--;
      var minCountDown = Math.floor(secLeft / 60);
      var secCountDown = Math.floor((secLeft % 60) * 100) / 100;
      props.setTimerNow({
        ...props.timerNow,
        min: minCountDown,
        sec: secCountDown,
      });
    }
  }
  const pauseCountDown = () => {
    props.setIsPaused(true);
    clearInterval(launch.current);
  };
  const reset = () => {
    props.setIsPaused(false);
    clearInterval(launch.current);
    props.setSessionLength(props.initialTimer.min);
    props.setTimerNow({
      ...props.timerNow,
      min: props.initialTimer.min,
      sec: props.initialTimer.sec,
    });
  };

  // ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It works! 
However, I am still not crystal clear what's reason behind this. 
"launch" is only used within this child component for setInterval(). It is not needed in its parent component. 
By the same logic, how about secLeft? It is used to store the length of time. 
Should we also ref for secLeft as well?

Comment: It looks like `secLeft` is calculated from `props`. I didn't notice that you modify it in `decrement` - you should probably just not modify it in `decrement` and just derive it from `props.timerNow.min` and `props.timerNow.sec`.

Comment: `ref`s are like instance variables in a class, if you're familiar with object-oriented programming.

Comment: `secLeft` is the total time period in the format of seconds, derived  from `props.timerNow.min` and `props.timerNow.sec`. Any reason why we should avoid using `secLeft`? I can remove `secLeft` and just use `props.timerNow.min` and `props.timerNow.sec` directly but just using `secLeft` makes the code a bit more tidy and readable.

Comment: Yes, that's fine,  `secLeft--` is just redundant then.

Comment: Actually I couldn't find any way to avoid assigning a variable to store the value of `parseInt(props.timerNow.min) * 60 + parseInt(props.timerNow.sec)` because we need decrement to happen from `decrement()`. I am just wondering what is the correct concept behind all this. How do we know when it is okay to use a variable and when we should use ref instead?